# How save project or website in one folder?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012

I want save a website but it's save in two folders. first folder contain .sln and second folder contain .aspx , app-data, webconfig.

How do I save all of them in a single folder?

This is image of my computer:

[image: http://i.cubeupload.com/FNDAYK.jpg]

Comment: The sln can not be, and must not be on the web site directory !

Comment: in 2010 work exaxtly but in 2012 not work